# Restore database from bak file with new database name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, smo

I need to create copy of database with new name. In my `asp.net mvc` project I use `smo` to create backup of database and than try to do restore. I do like this: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1849/backup-and-restore-sql-server-databases-programmatically-with-smo/.

But I get an exception:

> The file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\LocalClientTrakDB.mdf' cannot be overwritten.  It is being used by database 'LocalClientTrakDB'.
>   File 'LocalClientTrakDB' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\LocalClientTrakDB.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
>   The file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\LocalClientTrakDB_log.ldf' cannot be overwritten.  It is being used by database 'LocalClientTrakDB'.
>   File 'LocalClientTrakDB_log' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\LocalClientTrakDB_log.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
>   Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

My code to restore database:

```
static void DatabaseRestore(Server myServer, Database myDatabase)
{
    string newdbfilename = myDatabase.Name + "New";

    Restore restoreDB = new Restore();
    restoreDB.Database = newdbfilename;

    restoreDB.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
    restoreDB.Devices.AddDevice(@"C:\temp\TestFullDB.bak", DeviceType.File);

    restoreDB.ReplaceDatabase = true;
    restoreDB.NoRecovery = false;

    restoreDB.SqlRestore(myServer);
}
```

Have you any idea?

Comment: The error message tells you what the problem is (you can't overwrite files being used by an existing database) and what to do about it (use `WITH MOVE` to put the restored files somewhere else). So what is your difficulty, exactly?

Comment: Why I get it error if I set new name for database (db with this name doesn't exist)?

Comment: You get an error because you only set a **logical** database name - but that does **NOT** affect what the **physical files** will be called. So you need to do both: define a new logical database name (you already do that), and you **also** need to move your files to new locations/new names.

Comment: Do you mean I need to do like this: `restoreDB.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(...`?